# Is there a way of summing two vectors with different lengths in Scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp

Am a beginner to Scheme a dialect of Lisp, am trying to implement a function `sum-vector` that takes two vectors of numbers as arguments and returns a vector with the sum of the corresponding elements of the input vectors.

I have tried the following code but i can't figure out how to sum two vectors with different lengths.
Here is my current code

```
#lang scheme
(define sum-vector
  (lambda (vec-1 vec-2)
    (let* ((len (vector-length vec-1))
                                       
           (result (make-vector len)))
      (do ((index 0 (+ index 1)))
          ((= index len) result)
        (vector-set! result index
                     (+ (vector-ref vec-1 index)
                        (vector-ref vec-2 index)))))))

(sum-vector (vector 4 6 8 3) (vector 5 6 7))
```

When i run the above code it works perfectly for vectors with same lengths e.g `(sum-vector (vector 4 6 8) (vector 5 6 7))` returns `#(9 12 15)` I want it to work similarly for different lengths e.g `(sum-vector (vector 4 6 8 3) (vector 5 6 7))` should return `#(9 11 15 3)` but i can't figure out the logic for doing that.

Comment: there are two issues: (1) you have to make a vector whose size is the max of your inputs's length; I would call "max" on the respective lenghts; (2) then there are cases where you can't call "vector-ref" with an out-of-bounds index, so you could write an auxiliary function "vector-get" that checks the bounds and return a default value (zero) if the bound is too high or too low.

Comment: @coredump can you please workout a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to append zeros to each vector to make their lengths equal and then use [`vector-map`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-map%29%29):

```
(define (zero-vector len)
  (make-vector len 0))

(define (append-zeros vec max-len)
  (vector-append vec (zero-vector (- max-len (vector-length vec)))))

(define (sum-vector v1 v2)
  (let ((max-len (max (vector-length v1)
                      (vector-length v2))))
    (vector-map +
                (append-zeros v1 max-len)
                (append-zeros v2 max-len))))
```

Tests:

```
> (sum-vector (vector 1 2 3) (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6))
'#(2 4 6 4 5 6)
> (sum-vector (vector) (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
'#(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Comment: racket `vector-map` is different from SRFI-43 `vector-map`. Annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Another, Racket-specific way.

Racket has something called [comprehensions](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html), which allow for easy iteration over containers. In particular, [`for/vector`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/for.html#%28part._for_vector_and_for__vector%29) returns a vector of the results:

```lisp
> (define v1 (vector 4 6 8 3))
> (define v2 (vector 5 6 7))
> (for/vector ([e1 v1] [e2 v2]) (+ e1 e2))
'#(9 12 15)
```

Note that the resulting vector is the length of the shortest container being iterated over. You can tell it to produce a vector of a given length, though:

```
> (for/vector #:length (vector-length v1) ([e1 v1] [e2 v2]) (+ e1 e2))
'#(9 12 15 0)
```

It fills in the extra elements with 0. Combine that with [`vector-copy!`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._vector-copy%21%29%29), which copies a range of elements from one vector to another at given offsets to copy the extra elements from the larger vector to the smaller (Or do nothing if they're the same length), and you get:

```lisp
(define (sum-vector v1 v2)
  (let ([sum-helper
         (lambda (short long)
           (let ([result (for/vector #:length (vector-length long)
                                     ([e1 short] [e2 long])
                                     (+ e1 e2))])
             (vector-copy! result (vector-length short)
                           long (vector-length short) (vector-length long))
             result))])
    (if (< (vector-length v1) (vector-length v2))
        (sum-helper v1 v2)
        (sum-helper v2 v1))))
```

Examples:

```lisp
> (sum-vector (vector 4 6 8 3) (vector 5 6 7))
'#(9 12 15 3)
> (sum-vector (vector 1 2 3) (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6))
'#(2 4 6 4 5 6)
> (sum-vector (vector) (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8))
'#(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
```