# How can i compute the summation of two vectors in scheme(Dr Racket)

Tags: vector, sum, scheme, racket

I would like to implement my function sum-of-vectors , such that it takes two vectors of different numbers as arguments and it returns a vector with the summation of the corresponding elements of the captured vectors .
This is how it should be executed to test for the summation of the vectors
where vector 1 is (vector 4 6 8 3) , and vector 2 is : (vector 5 6 7)

Testing Expression: (sum-vector (vector 4 6 8 3) (vector 5 6 7)) => #(9 11 15 3)

SIMILAR QUESTION : There is a close solution to this which is on URL ,
[Is there a way of summing two vectors with different lengths in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924497/is-there-a-way-of-summing-two-vectors-with-different-lengths-in-scheme)

but the difference is that  , it displays '#(2 4 6 4 5 6) with a comma the start of the question , yet the actual output from my requirement should not have an apostrophe(') in the output vector. it should be #(9 11 15 3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way of summing two vectors with different lengths in Scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924497/is-there-a-way-of-summing-two-vectors-with-different-lengths-in-scheme)

Comment: Thank you for sharing that , but that one is just close to answering the question ,  (sum-vector (vector 1 2 3) (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6)) , it displays   '#(2 4 6 4 5 6) with a comma the start of the question , but the actual output should not have a comma(,) in the output vector. it should be  #(9 11 15 3)

Comment: What's the logic of `(sum-vector (vector 1 2 3) (vector 1 2 3 4 5 6))` returning `#(9 11 15 3)`?

Comment: @Shawn The output that starts with an apostrophe is a list , but this one is a vector with arguments , not with list items. that is the difference

Comment: How are you getting those numbers in the output from that input?

Comment: And apostrophes? Are you confusing how a particular scheme implementation prints a v alue vs the value itself?

Comment: @Shawn check this URL , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71924497/is-there-a-way-of-summing-two-vectors-with-different-lengths-in-scheme , and you will get how the output is , recheck the question i have tried to elaborate more on it too , i made some edits to my question.

Comment: ... have you tried running the code?

Comment: Yes i ran the code , it returns a list of vectors i  don't need a list    ' #(9 11 15 3) , i just need a vector itself as #(9 11 15 3). @Shawn

Comment: That's not a list. That's a vector. It's just printed in quoted form for some reason in whatever scheme you're using (Maybe so it can be read with `read`?)

Comment: The 2nd element in the output should be `12` , isn't it ??

Comment: Yes the second element is 12, am very much okay with that , maybe to ask @Shawn do you have a different way of having it printed which is not in a quoted form ?

Comment: @wandie In DrRacket, choose Language settings, Choose Language, Show Details, set Output Style to print or write and compare outputs.

Comment: @wandie Also see this: https://docs.racket-lang.org/drracket/output-syntax.html

Comment: And https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html#%28part._print-vectors%29

Answer (score 0):

A function to process corresponding elements of two lists which may differ in length
is easily written down: write a *stub*, with *signature* and *purpose*, and a
*minimal example*:

```
(define (sum-of-lists l1 l2) ;; ListOfNumber ListOfNumber -> ListOfNumber
  ;; produce list of sums of corresponding elements of l1, l2
  ;; length of result is greater of lengths of l1, l2
  '#())

(check-expect (sum-of-lists '() '()) '())
```

Add the next examples and fill out the function:

```
(check-expect (sum-of-lists '()  '(1)) `(1))
(check-expect (sum-of-lists '(2) '())  `(2))
(check-expect (sum-of-lists '(3) '(4)) `(7))

(define (sum-of-lists l1 l2) ;; ListOfNumber ListOfNumber -> ListOfNumber
  ;; produce list of sums of corresponding elements of l1, l2
  ;; length of result is greater of lengths of l1, l2
  (cond
    [(and (empty? l1) (empty? l2)) empty ]
    [(empty? l1) (cons (first l2) (sum-of-lists l1 (rest l2))) ]
    [(empty? l2) (cons (first l1) (sum-of-lists (rest l1) l2)) ]
    [else (cons (+ (first l1) (first l2)) (sum-of-lists (rest l1) (rest l2))) ]))
```

(note how the 4 arms of the `cond` echo the 4 examples)

Now the required `sum-of-vectors` is just:

```
(define (sum-of-vectors von1 von2) ;; VectorOfNumber VectorOfNumber -> VectorOfNumber
  ;; produce vector of sums of corresponding elements of von1, von2
  ;; length of result is greater of lengths of von1, von2
  (list->vector (sum-of-lists (vector->list von1) (vector->list von2))))

(check-expect (sum-of-vectors (vector 4 6 8 3) (vector 5 6 7)) (vector 9 12 15 3))

Welcome to DrRacket, version 8.4 [cs].
Language: Advanced Student.
All 5 tests passed!
> (sum-of-vectors '#(1 2 3) '#(1 2 3 4 5 6))
(vector 2 4 6 4 5 6)
>
```